# Way to calculate size of group of units $\{0<x<n:\gcd(x,n)=1\}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We were talking about a way to figure out how many numbers are in such a set that $\{0<x<n:\gcd(x,n)=1\}$. The professor told us not to worry about how to find it but I was curious if there is a formula or something for it?

Comment: It is Euler's totient function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function

Comment: Although is solved by that definition, you tagged combinatorics. So, you can see that set as $\{x\in[n]:gcd(x,n)=1\}=[n]\setminus(\cup _{p|n,p\text{ p prime}} \{x\in [n]:p|gcd(x,n)\})$ and try to use an inclusion-exclusion argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, H. H. Rugh's comment above gives a perfectly good Wikipedia link.  Here are the highlights:

- The size of this group is defined to be the value of the *Euler totient function*.  That is,
  $$
  \varphi(n) = \{0<x<n:\gcd(x,n)=1\}
  $$
- If $p$ is prime, $\varphi(p^k) = p^k - p^{k-1} = p^k(1 - 1/p)$
- If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m) \varphi(n)$
- With these two facts, we can compute $\varphi$ for any number whose prime factorization we know.  For example:
  $$
  \varphi(3500) = \varphi(2^2\times 5^3\times 7) = 
  \varphi(2^2)\varphi(5^3)\varphi(7) = 
  (2^2 - 2)(5^3 - 5^2)(7-1) = 1200
  $$

Comment: Is this correct? 15 = 3*5, φ(15) = 15* (1-1/3)*(1-1/5) = 15*(2/3)*(4/5) =8

Comment: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch05s02.html

Comment: Yes, that's right.